# fancybox title as element and thumbnail helper

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying to utilize the title as element script along with the Thumbnail helper. If I use the same class name for both, ie.. (.fancybox-thumb), only the title as element works.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

title as element

```
$(".fancybox-thumb")
        .attr('rel', 'gallery')
        .fancybox({
            beforeLoad: function() {
                var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');

                if (id) {
                    el = $('#' + id);

                    if (el.length) {
                        this.title = el.html();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Thumbnail helper

```
    $(".fancybox-thumb")
        .attr('rel', 'gallery')
        .fancybox({
             prevEffect : 'none',
             nextEffect : 'none',
             helpers    : {
                 title  : {
                     type: 'outside'
                },
                 thumbs : {
                     width  : 60,
                     height : 60
                }
            }

        });
```

If I use the same class name for both ie.. (.fancybox-thumb), only the title as element works.

```
<div id="main" class="wrapper clearfix">              
      <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6111/6285920681_67917e8062_b.jpg" title="walk in the park (ewitsoe)">
        <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6111/6285920681_67917e8062_m.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>

    <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6106/6347065961_bb73745e70_b.jpg" data-title-id="title-1">
        <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6106/6347065961_bb73745e70_m.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <div id="title-1" class="hidden">
        This is 1st title. <a href="http://google.com" target="blank">Some link</a>
    </div><!--title-1-->
</div> <!-- #main -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrate both API options inside a single script like :

```
$(".fancybox-thumb").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
    prevEffect: 'none',
    nextEffect: 'none',
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'outside'
        },
        thumbs: {
            width: 60,
            height: 60
        }
    },
    beforeLoad: function() {
        var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');
        if (id) {
            el = $('#' + id);
            if (el.length) {
                this.title = el.html();
            }
        }
    }
});​
```

Of course, don't forget to load fancybox's thumbnail helper css and js files like :

```
<!-- Add fancyBox - thumbnail helper -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=2.1.3" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
```

**EDIT** : you could create different galleries grouping the gallery elements under a different parent container like

```
<div id="gallery1" class="gallery">
    <p>gallery one</p>
    <a class="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7100/6917703112_d18e3e1b95_b.jpg">one</a>
    <a class="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7140/7061825385_0ccedf2a8e_b.jpg">two</a>
</div>
<div id="gallery2" class="gallery">
    <p>gallery two</p>
    <a class="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7065/7058141285_064170310e_b.jpg">one</a>
    <a class="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5333/7061356373_1af921fd78_b.jpg">two</a>
</div>
<div id="gallery3" class="gallery">
    <p>gallery three</p>
    <a class="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7069/7060779347_fbee5aae15_b.jpg">one</a>
    <a class="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7053/6918451990_20fa76f338_b.jpg">two</a>
</div>
```

​
**NOTICE** that I used the same `class` for the parent container but a different `ID`, which will be used to distinguish galleries from each other.

Then with a little jQuery, create the fancybox galleries without needing a different script for each of them:

```
// loop through each parent container and set rel attribute accordingly
$("div.gallery").each(function() {
    var thisID = this.id;
    $(this).find(".fancybox-thumb").attr("rel", thisID).fancybox({
        // API options here
    });
}); // each​​​​​
```

See a **[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RJajg/)**

Comment: THanks @JFK, this works great, for one gallery. I am using multiple galleries so what happens now is it strings all the thumbnails together as if one gallery. I suppose I could give each gallery it's own class (.fancybox-thumb1) etc. this seems clunky though.
Do you see a way to alter the script; at this point I assume .attr('rel','gallery') to recognize multiple galleries?